# Heroic fantasy god game

Tags: identify-this-game

I am looking for the name of a board game that I played in uni (6 years ago). It's an heroic fantasy game where each player is god and can take control of any race on the board and have them fight any other race. Each player is secretly dealt a race that they have to make grow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just googled the description and this came up (Age of Gods)
https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/13/13636.phtml
Is this the one?